# Multiple SQL replication types

Tags: sql-server, merge, replication, transactional

We currently have two SQL databases that are utilizing a merge replication. We would like to setup a separate transactional replication off one of the databases to a third database. Is this possible? If so, do we need to change anything with our distributor?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes this is possible.  Nothing needs to change with the Distributor.

However, if you ever have a Merge node receive data from a Transactional Replication topology then you will need to make sure the property **@published_in_tran_pub** for your Merge articles is set to **true** to ensure the Merge triggers fire properly.  It sounds like this won't apply in your case unless the third database is a Merge publisher/subscriber.