# Where can I see the @published_in_tran_pub property?

Tags: replication, merge-replication, transactional-replication

We have a merge replication that sources on a subscription of a transactional replication. According to this source ([Multiple SQL replication types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21999645/multiple-sql-replication-types)) I need to set the @published_in_tran_pub to true.

So far so good, however now I would like to check if the property is indeed set to true. Does anyone know how to do this?

**Microsoft**: *This merge replication example returns the properties of the published article.*
TSQL

```
DECLARE @publication AS sysname;
SET @publication = N'AdvWorksSalesOrdersMerge';

USE [AdventureWorks2012]
EXEC sp_helpmergearticle
 @publication = @publication;
GO
```

Unfortunately the above query does not return information about the @published_in_tran_pub property.

Thanks in advance

Comment: @brandonwilliams I think you can answer my question since you answered related questions. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can query [sysmergearticles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189825.aspx) to check the value of the property **@published_in_tran_pub**.

Comment: Thank you very much! Looking to your profile, it seems you have a lot of experience with replication. Could you be so kind to have a look at my post here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26999358/replicate-a-filtered-subset-of-data-merge-or-transactional-replication thanks again!